# CodeProperty's CodeType is suddenly gone

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4, c#-code-model

I'm busy creating an assembly that will gather CodeModel information wich in turn is used to generate code with a T4 template.

I'm struggling with CodeModel because of the lack of good information. I found a few books describing the CodeModel but only the true basics. Found no in-depth documentation.

The past week I created the mentioned assembly and the following construct worked fine for over 4 days.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The CodeType of the property
    /// </summary>
    public CodeType CodeType
    {
        get
        {
            if (!m_CodeTypeInitialized)
            {
                CodeTypeRef codeTypeRef = CodeProperty.Type;
                m_CodeType = codeTypeRef.CodeType;

                m_CodeTypeInitialized = true;
            }

            return m_CodeType;
        }
    }
```

Yesterday suddenly this construct no longer returns the CodeType anymore. I've now changed the code to this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The CodeType of the property
    /// </summary>
    public CodeType CodeType
    {
        get
        {
            if (!m_CodeTypeInitialized)
            {
                if (CodeProperty.IsCodeType)
                {
                    CodeTypeRef codeTypeRef = CodeProperty.Type;
                    m_CodeType = codeTypeRef.CodeType;
                }

                m_CodeTypeInitialized = true;
            }

            return m_CodeType;
        }
    }
```

This no longer causes an exception but the outcome is always 'null'. I'm lost. What could cause the CodeProperty to, all of a sudden, loose it's CodeType?

I really need the CodeType because a lot of code is hinging on it's information.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a work arround like this. It's not nice but it works fine:

```
        private FileCodeModel m_FileCodeModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// The FileCodeModel the entity of this property is found in.
    /// </summary>
    public FileCodeModel FileCodeModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_FileCodeModel == null)
            {
                m_FileCodeModel = EntityMetadata.FileCodeModel;
            }

            return m_FileCodeModel;
        }
    }

    private Project m_Project;

    /// <summary>
    /// The project this properties entity is contained in.
    /// </summary>
    public Project ContainingProject
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Project == null)
            {
                m_Project = FileCodeModel.Parent.ContainingProject;
            }

            return m_Project;
        }
    }

    private CodeModel m_CodeModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// The CodeModel for the properties entity.
    /// </summary>
    public CodeModel CodeModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_CodeModel == null)
            {
                m_CodeModel = ContainingProject.CodeModel;
            }

            return m_CodeModel;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// De CodeType van de property
    /// </summary>
    public CodeType CodeType
    {
        get
        {
            if (!m_CodeTypeInitialized)
            {
                if (CodeProperty.IsCodeType)
                {
                    CodeTypeRef codeTypeRef = CodeProperty.Type;
                    m_CodeType = codeTypeRef.CodeType;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_CodeType = CodeModel.CodeTypeFromFullName(CodeProperty.Type.AsFullName);
                }

                m_CodeTypeInitialized = true;
            }

            return m_CodeType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just realized that this only works if the type I'm looking for is contained in the same Project. And also it does not really answer the question :-(